# Angularjs - Browser Back or Back button implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back

I am working on an application which is using route methods to open webpages for different modules, it is basically a single page application with route methods to load the HTMLs in the body content.

I have a search results page and then move to a new page via a link and that proceeding page has a back button to take us to search results page. On doing that, we are going to search results page but the page context is lost it shows a blank search results page, the old data is gone.

How can we maintain that old data using angularjs, as the application is using angularjs?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the back button redirects to the previous url, one way to resolve your problem would be to use the service $location and base your search on a query string in the url.

See this documentation for more informations : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location